# How do you fix memory leak in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am struggling for past day about this particular case in my app.

Throughout the day, application fetches data from the other database (around 400k entries) and processes it. After processing, application maps items to collections inside this application's database and saves them.

Everything goes fine until the end of the function. Currently, I am invoking it through a http request but it is going to be a CRON job. So basically, after hitting the .res() endpoint, the CPU does not slows down on usage and the heap memory is not freeing. I am just wondering what could be happening.

I read a little about identifying memory leaks and found out this. [2] is the processor, that was used to process data.

```
x[ 1] App                         Mem:  68 MB    CPU:  1 %  online xx                                                                                                                                                                   x
x[ 2] App                         Mem: 182 MB    CPU: 135 %  online xx                                                                                                                                                                   x
x[ 3] App                         Mem:  60 MB    CPU:  0 %  online xx                                                                                                                                                                   x
x[ 4] App                         Mem:  60 MB    CPU:  0 %  online xx                                                                                                                                                                   x
x[ 5] App                         Mem:  59 MB    CPU:  0 %  online
```

As you can clearly see, memory and CPU is way higher than on the other node instances. I thought .res() would kill the task, release memory and slow the cpu down but it doesn't.

I use Expressjs, have undertaken MVC pattern and store all logic in class components. Is there any way to free up this memory as I have tried to apply some sort of cleaning-up function but it did not work :(.
I have started running out of ideas on how to identify what could be the possible problem. Maybe there is something obvious, that I do not pay attention to but to be honest I don't have that much experience in node to find it out.

Comment: In order to release the memory, you have to drop all references to objects. Once an objects is no longer referenced it will be eligible for garbage collection. If data is not GCd then you're retaining some references somewhere.

Comment: That's always a good lead. Thank you.

Comment: @VLAZ, Are there any good practices of applying it in express, or classic delete should do the work too?

Comment: Not much different than any of JavaScript. Use local variables, don't keep globals, don't keep references to things for later. Once a function exists, all local variables it has will not be referenced any more and should be automatically suitable for GC.